# Reformat JSON array using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, csv

I have a small PHP script that pulls in a CSV file and creates a JSON array from this.

**However**, I'd like to change the formatting of my outputted JSON array.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$file = fopen('food.csv', 'r');
$allfile = [];
$idsColumnsWanted = array_flip([0, 1, 2]);
while (false !== $fields = fgetcsv($file)) {
    $allfile[] = array_intersect_key($fields, $idsColumnsWanted);
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

**Output:**
`var data = [["McDonalds","Fast Food","London"],["Marios","Italian","Manchester"]];`

How do I transform my CSV into the following:

```
var data = [
{name:"McDonald's Fast Food",location:"London"},
{name:"Marios Italian",location:"Manchester"}
];
```

So it basically merges the first 2 items and adds `name` & `location`.

My `food.csv` file is:

```
McDonalds,Fast Food,London
Marios,Italian,Manchester
```

Comment: just edit the raw data you read with fgetcsv. you *should* know how to manipulate arrays and how to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time please try something by yourself:

```
$data = [["McDonalds", "Fast Food", "London"], ["Marios", "Italian", "Manchester"]];
$newData = [];
foreach ($data as $info) {
    $newData[] = [
        'name' => $info[0] . " " . $info[1],
        'location' => $info[2]
    ];
}
var_dump(json_encode($newData));
```

**Output**

```
string '[{"name":"McDonalds Fast Food","location":"London"},{"name":"Marios Italian","location":"Manchester"}]' (length=104)
```

You need to create a new array in the desired format, and simple `json_encode` it.

Comment: With a bit of tweaking, this worked perfectly. Many thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you consider using jQuery - there it is

```
var data = [["McDonalds","Fast Food","London"],["Marios","Italian","Manchester"]];

var formated_data = {};

$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    formated_data[key] = {name: val[0] + ' ' + val[1], location: val[2]}
});

console.log(formated_data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Open CSV File then parse the CSV into an array. 
Flow this Line,

```
    <?php 
     $file="1_23.csv";
     $csv= file_get_contents($file);
     $array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csv));
     $json = json_encode($array);
     print_r($json);
    ?>
```